# Can I get an array of all the hooks names ( default & created ones ) of a prestashop theme?

Tags: module, prestashop, hook, prestashop-1.7

I want to get the names of all the hooks (default and created ones) in a prestashop theme so that I register a module to all hooks.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this method

```
Hook::getHooks();
```